Bpy script, issue w/ my rotations on a sin curve
trying to figure out why the downward slope of the sin worm is getting flattened (cross sections are 'over-rotated' ). Btw I get the same kind of thing doing slope with dx/dy (prev - next slope). Any ideas. Thanks.


Don't post images of text, post the actual code so we can debug it ourselves. If your code won't work by itself then pare it back to get a workable example that still contains your issue.

The correct formula is:

tan(slope_angle) = height * cos(x.value)

So:

slope_angle = math.atan(height * math.cos(x.value))

